# RedirectToAction does not call the target controller and action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This post action is called from a ajax jquery dialog.

When I have a template selected it should run the RedirectToAction method but the UnitController and GetTemplateRootUnits action is never hit?

What do I wrong?

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Open(int selectedTemplateId)
    {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {

     return RedirectToAction("GetTemplateRootUnits", "Unit", new { TemplateId = selectedTemplateId });

     }
     else
     {
         return LoadOpenTemplates();
     }          
    }
```

my route table:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Main", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

my target controller/action to call:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonNetResult GetTemplateRootUnits(int templateId)
{
 IEnumerable<Unit> units = _unitDataProvider.GetTemplateRootUnits(templateId);
 return new JsonNetResult(new { data = units });
}

 function openTemplate(dlg, form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    dlg.dialog("close");
                    $('#TreeDiv').empty();
                    loadUnits(response.data);
                }
                else {  // Reload the dialog with the form to show model/validation errors                    
                    dlg.html(response);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Two things to check: firstly, is the modelstate actually valid?  Secondly, if it is, what does your route table look like?

Comment: yes it is valid else the code would not hid the RedirectToAction. I use the default route table of asp.net mvc 4.

Comment: It always shows the same jquery dialog where I can choose the templates. I have updated my code.

Comment: Have you used something like fiddler to see the actual HTTP request/responses that are being sent between the browser and server (in this case VS). Perhaps the issue is that the browser isn't doing what you expect it to do.

Comment: ah hell of a crap. Due to my service refactorings I added somehow the same ninject binding to my IUnitDataProvider 2 times which is causing an controller server error which I got when I tried the redirectToAction on another controller... :/

Answer (score 1):

`RedirectToAction` will not work when you use an AJAX POST
see:

[RedirectToAction not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225030/redirecttoaction-not-working)

You need to use javascript to redirect in this case.

A couple of approaches:

[How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

[RedirectToAction not redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965401/redirecttoaction-not-redirecting?rq=1)